# Layered header structure in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, header, nested, layer

I'm trying to create a layered header in bootstrap. A background image on the bottom most layer, the title is on top of the background image (always top-centered), the logo is on top of the background image too (always top-right), the slogan is on top of the background image too (always right aligned) and the quote is on top of the background image (center aligned). The title, logo, slogan and quote could all be on the same layer but all on top of the background image.

How can I structure the rows to display in layers?

View link for an illustration. http://varsang.com/header.jpg

Blue is the background image. Would like to keep the same format but all responsive when the screen size becomes smaller.

Comment: Please make a working fiddle, what have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

You should really make an effort and at least show the code you have tried so far.

This is however a very simple problem so here you go.

Simple create your 'container > row > col' structure as normal but place another div around your elements and make your image the background image of that element. Simples.

I haven't replicated your desired row/col structure as I'm assuming that you know how to do that using different col sizes for different screen sizes if required as per Bootstrap's docs.

```
<div class="my-background">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                YOUR CONTENT
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```